# Completion of coalgebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, operads, coalgebras, rational-homotopy-theory

Is it possible to complete commutative dg associative (conilpotent) coalgebras over $\mathbb{Q}$ in a way so that when we complete the symmetric coalgebra $Sym(V)$ it becomes completed with respect to the word length?

A similar question is if it is possible to complete coalgebras over a Koszul operad $\mathcal P$ so that the bar construction of an algebra over $\mathcal P^!$ becomes completed with respect to the word length.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what you mean by "completed with respect to the word length"? Depending on what you mean, I might have an answer to your question.

Comment: @DavidWhite: If $\{x_i\}$  is a collection where $x_i\in Sym^i(V)$, then I want that the infinite sum $\sum_ix_i$ to be well-defined. In the case for the bar construction, I want something similar, but now in the category of coalgebras over $\mathcal P^!$.

Comment: It looks like if you want to take products instead of direct sums, am I right? What obstruction do you find?

Comment: @FernandoMuro: Yes, is there any construction on coalgebras so that when I apply it on say $Sym(V)$ it becomes $\prod Sym^i(V)$?